# Working with list inside a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following dataframe -

```
ID | Column1 |
0  |  []     | 
1  |  [1,2]  | 
2  |  []     |
```

I want a column which gives the length of the list in column1. Result should look like -

```
ID | Column1 | Column2 |
0  |  []     |   0     |
1  |  [1,2]  |   2     |
2  |  []     |   0     |
```

I tried using lambda function but it is not giving the number of rows in the data frame as every entry in column 2 -

```
df1 = df.assign(Column2 = lambda x: (len(x['Column1'])))
```

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: `df['Column2']=df['Column1'].map(len)`

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks. Can you please point out why what I am trying to use is wrong?

Comment: you are assigning the length of your dataframe to Column2

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. You can write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd iterate through each element in `Column1`, get its length, save it in a list and then assign it to a new `Column2`. This would be summarized with:

```
df['Column2'] = [len(x) for x in df['Column1']]
```